# Input box in button bar

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am attempting to place a input box in a bootstrap 3 button bar but it is not aligned as expected.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
        <div class="btn-toolbar text-center">
            <div class="btn-group">
                   <div class="input-group col-xs-3">
                     <input type="text" class="form-control">
                     <span class="input-group-addon">$</span>
                   </div>
            </div>
            <div class="btn-group">
                <button class="btn btn-default">Button 1</button>
                <button class="btn btn-default">Button 2</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

It works fine if I use a vanilla input but the buttons in the second btn-group move down to the next row when I attempt to use a input group. Any idea on how I can have them appear on the same row?

Here is a fiddle demonstrating the problem

http://jsfiddle.net/6XST2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the col class to the parent element, the `.btn-group`. Change this:

```
<div class="btn-group">
    <div class="input-group col-xs-3">
```

To this:

```
<div class="btn-group col-xs-3">
    <div class="input-group">
```

Otherwise, the `btn-group` is filling the whole width.
http://jsfiddle.net/6XST2/3/

Answer (score 0):

try to see this solution
and in this solution you must change the class `col-xs-3` to `col-xs-12`

http://jsfiddle.net/6XST2/1/